# Add Record to Static row at Bottom of UltraGrid

Tags: c#, database, infragistics

I am a newb to Infragistics and have the following problem:
I have three UltraGrids on the form, one for each of three tables.

I want a fixed row at the bottom of a each band(for the table it references) so that one could add a new record into this row, like one could do with in MS-Access.

I finally got a "static/fix" row at the bottom of the Grid, but 
i can for the love of me figure out how to edit it.

I HAVE DONE EXTENSIVE SEARCHING and even asked the Infragistics
experts over at http://blogs.infragistics.com/forums.... but to no Avail..

When at runtime i select this grey row, the Foreign-key(MainAction's ID field) appears but i cannot enter information into the other fields

To summarize:

I want to be able to edit the grey row at the bottom of each ban and when/if i press enter, it should add it to the database.

Kind Regards

Markus

Comment: What is the value of CellClickAction on the Override object of DisplayLayout?

Comment: @Steve: The value was RowSelect, which i chanced to EditAndSelectText.

This did almost eveything i wanted. I guess all i have to do is update the dataset.

Thanks ALOT

Comment: well I post this comment as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should activate the row setting the
`grid.DisplayLayout.Override.CellClickActivation = Activation.Edit` 
or `Activation.EditAndSelectText`

Comment: It is also necessary to set grid.DisplayLayout.Override.AllowAddnew to TemplateOnBottom for the add new row to be present.